# Getting Vino working on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, vnc

I'm trying to get Vino up and running on Lubuntu 16.04 and not having success. I've installed Vino, and run the `vino-preferences` applet to configure Vino. I've set the applet to always be shown.

What seems to be happening is running `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` will seem to start the server, but the applet will not open on the desktop, the server is not advertised via zeroconf, and I can not connect either by Zeroconf or direct ip on a local network. No VNC client sees the server, so it hasn't actually properly started up.

I think there is some incompatibility between Lubuntu, installed packages, or the window manager that is holding up Vino from properly starting. Vino doesn't keep error logs, and I haven't found anything regarding it in xsession or other logs.

I have tried Vino on multiple clean installs of Lubuntu and get the same result each time. Vino won't work. I have tried Vino on Ubuntu (Unity), Xubuntu, and Ubuntu-Mate VMs and have had no problem - the server starts, applet launches, is advertised via Zeroconf, and I can connect from a client. Also, this is not the well-known encryption issue - I have set encryption to `false.`

I want to export my existing desktop over VNC, so my options are Vino or x11vnc. I tried x11vnc and find it terribly slow and underperforming compared to Vino. When Vino works, it performs well and is easy to set up, so it would be my choice.

Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by something different, but I managed to make Vino work on Lubuntu recently and decided to share it.

1. Install the server with `sudo apt install vino`.
2. Edit the preferences. It should be possible to either do it from the console with `gsettings` or with Dconf Editor - I used the latter.

   1. Install Dconf Editor with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`.
   2. Launch it.
   3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, paste "/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/" and confirm, or select "org", then "gnome", "desktop" and "remote-access".
3. Uncheck "prompt-enabled".
4. Start the server with `/usr/libexec/vino-server` or however else You prefer.

I think it should be enough to be able to connect to the server, BUT there is no authentication method enabled so it seems pretty dangerous.

To enable password authentication do the following:

1. In "/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/authentication-methods" in Dconf Editor set "Custom value" to "['vnc']".
2. Obtain encoded version of chosen password with `base64 <Your password>` and copy it.
3. Paste the encoded version of the password as "Custom value" in "/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/vnc-password" in Dconf Editor.